# Generate all possible outcomes from lists with two different functions

Tags: python, list, function

I am quite new to programming in general. I am working in Python and I am encountering some difficulties.

I have two functions with 4 varaiables each, they  both contain the same variables. For the variables I created 4 lists with the different values for the variables.
Now I would like Python to calculate/generate all the possible outcomes for the two functions.

Subsequently, I would like to plot these outcomes in a scatterplot but for now is there someone that can help me with this problem.

I have to tried to make a list with all combinations but I cannot link this to the 2 functions.
So `x1` can be `6`, `7`, `8`.
`x2` can be `4`, `5`, `6`.
`x3` can be `2`, `3`, `5`, etc

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
#def heat transmission
def BIC (x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return (75 / x1) + (85 / x2) + (55 / x3) + (12 * x4)
    

#def TOjuli
def TOjuli(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return ((400 * 1000) / ((75 / x1) + (85 / x2) + (55 / x3) + (12 * x4)))
    


#variables

# Different modules
x1_options = [6, 7, 8]
x2_options = [4, 5, 6]
x3_options = [2, 3, 5]
x4_options = [0.5, 0.4, 0.6]
```

Comment: btw Your functions both return `None`. Did you mean (for the first function): `return (75 / x1) + (85 / x2) + (55 / x3) + (12 * x4)`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean ( I think) I've edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```py
import itertools

def BIC (x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return (75 / x1) + (85 / x2) + (55 / x3) + (12 * x4)

#def TOjuli
def TOjuli(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return ((400 * 1000) / ((75 / x1) + (85 / x2) + (55 / x3) + (12 * x4)))

x1_options = [6, 7, 8]
x2_options = [4, 5, 6]
x3_options = [2, 3, 5]
x4_options = [0.5, 0.4, 0.6]

''' UPDATE: print a selection of the combinations of options '''
combinations = list(itertools.product(x1_options, x2_options, x3_options, x4_options))
for c in combinations:
    print(c, BIC(*c))
```

Output: (first 10 lines)

```
(6, 4, 2, 0.5) 67.25
(6, 4, 2, 0.4) 66.05
(6, 4, 2, 0.6) 68.45
(6, 4, 3, 0.5) 58.08333333333333
(6, 4, 3, 0.4) 56.883333333333326
(6, 4, 3, 0.6) 59.28333333333333
(6, 4, 5, 0.5) 50.75
(6, 4, 5, 0.4) 49.55
(6, 4, 5, 0.6) 51.95
(6, 5, 2, 0.5) 63.0
```

Comment: I want to find all the possible combinations/outcomes, so in both functions.
{ combinations = list(itertools.product(x1_options, x2_options, x3_options, x4_options))
print(combinations) }
If I use this line of code e.g., it shows me all the possible combinations but now I want to have them calculated within the functions.